# Proper Method for Setting Up Windows IOT on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, windows-iot

I have scoured the web looking for some indication of what I'm doing wrong to no avail.  Here is what I've got:

- Raspberry Pi 3 - Model B V1.2 2015
- Lexar 300x 64GB Micro SD
- Windows IOT Core Dashboard [Link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard)

I have tried everything in this [Post](https://www.osr.com/blog/2016/04/15/secrets-using-win10-on-the-rpi-3/), and several others.

**Question:** How can I get Windows IOT Core running on my Raspberry Pi 3?

**Amendment** I see all of the files on the SD, if I plug it into my PC.  When I fire up the Raspberry PI, I get flashing red and green then just flashing red.  Hooked HDMI up and see nothing.  Can't ping the Raspberry and it doesn't show up as a device in the Windows IOT Dashboard.

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly isn't working? E.g. what LEDs light up on your Pi, have you tried a different OS or SD?

Comment: Thanks @DarthVader Add some detail. Basically no signs of life after SD flash. Even ffu file approach. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an SD card which isn't supported - that might be the problem.

[You can find a list of supported SD cards here.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist#Storage)

I had similar problems to you with this process when I used a 64GB unsupported card - after I swapped it for a card on the supported list, I was able to install Windows 10 IOT Core and run it successfully.

I'd recommend you try setting up a supported SD card through the Windows IOT Dashboard and [follow the setup process here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard). I found it helpful to have the Pi connected to my router by a cable for the first boot, and also to connect a USB keyboard and HDMI monitor also.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.  I remember reading that, and thinking no way thats the issue, but the fact that you experienced this issue directly give me the confidence I need to go buy another SD card.

Comment: That was it.  Who'd a thunk?! - Thanks Jeremy.  I guess all SD cards are not created equal :)

Comment: Excellent - glad it worked!